# Beaglebone cannot connect to internet using ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, internet, beagleboneblack

I've been trying to get my Beaglebone Black to connect to internet using an ethernet cable plugged direct into my Netgear router. I have tried many things but nothing has worked so far.

**Here are some relevant outputs.**

systemctl

```
# Yesterday, internet not working
● networking.service    loaded failed failed  Raise network interfaces
# Today after reflashing beaglebone, internet still not working
networking.service    loaded active exited    Raise network interfaces
```

ip address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can 
3: can1: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can 
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f6:fd:8a:ec:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.123/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:8806:502:b00:a2f6:fdff:fe8a:ec7e/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 86390sec preferred_lft 86390sec
    inet6 fe80::a2f6:fdff:fe8a:ec7e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
68.105.28.11 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
68.105.28.12 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
68.105.29.11 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10 
192.168.0.1 dev eth0 scope link
192.168.6.0/30 dev usb1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.6.2 linkdown 
192.168.7.0/30 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.2 linkdown 
212.227.81.55 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

host google.com

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

ping www.google.com

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ping 192.168.0.1 (router)

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8199ms
```

ping 192.168.0.39 (my computer, connected to same router via ethernet)

```
PING 192.168.0.39 (192.168.0.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.39: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.432 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.39: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.324 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.39: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.389 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.39: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.387 ms
--- 192.168.0.39 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.324/0.383/0.432/0.038 ms
```

I have no idea how to fix this. It started working yesterday when I started writing this question then it started working mysteriously. I rebooted this morning and it's not working again.

Comment: If you can ping WAN IP's but not by name then it may help to edit /etc/resolv.conf
Add **nameserver 8.8.8.8** See if that helps.

Comment: **nslookup google.com** will show you you're DNS server Address for diagnostics also

Comment: did you fix the problem? or not?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/etc/network/interfaces` then add:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100 # or whatever static IP you want
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

After rebooting, the Beaglebone pings Google successfully.